# Finding the Extremals of a Functional J.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, functional-equations, mathematical-physics

The functional $J$ is defined on smooth functions $y \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $y(a) = u$, $y(b) = v$ and is given by

$$J[y]=\int_a^b \sqrt{y} \sqrt{1+(y')^2}\, dx.$$

I have found the Euler-Lagrange equation to be
$\sqrt{y} \sqrt{1+(y')^2} - y' \frac{\sqrt{y}(y')^2}{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}} = k$   for some constand $k$.

solving for $y'$ I got $y' = \sqrt{y/k^2 -1}$

Please could you confirm if this is correct and how to complete the problem from here?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: By $\sqrt y$, do you mean $\sqrt{|y|}$?

Comment: @anonymous : This is physics, and he probably wants everything to be nice and differentiable... so you might as well assume $a \ge 0$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: But even if $a$ and $b$ are positive, $y \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ will not be, in general; and that function is supposed to live on all of $C[a,b]$.

Comment: It is probably safe to say treat a>=0 for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the substitution $u = \frac{y}{k^2} - 1$.

You get that $k^2 \frac{du}{dt} = u^\frac{1}{2}$, which is easy to solve with separation of variables.

Comment: Ok I tried the u substitution and got y =(1/2)x + k^2 .  So The extremals of J[y] are straight lines. Is this correct?

Comment: does $y = \frac{1}{2} x + k^2$ really solve the differential equation?

Comment: No. I'm not sure how to solve the Diff Eq I'm afraid.

Comment: you can write the equation above as $ \int k^2 u^{-\frac{1}{2}}du = \int dt$ and then you get $2 u^{\frac{1}{2}} k^2 = t$. Now solve for $u$ and resubtitute in $y$

Comment: oh I got it now. Thank you so much!